# Explanation of app/code vs vendor directories please

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I'm looking for an explanation of the `app/code/[vendor]` and `vendor/[vendor]` directories?  (For M2.1)

Some online sources (such as  [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2)) say to put a new module in `app/code/[vendor]`, yet in 2.1 there is no such directory, and modules are conspicuously in `vendor/[vendor]`.  Meanwhile the official doc page on the Magento file system say "information will be added later".

Which is correct? What's the history -- did this change at some point?  Can I read docs that refer to `app/code` and just do the same thing in `vendor/`?

Comment: You can use package manager(Composer) when you publish your module for community development. Otherwise you can stick with app/code folder  https://tutsplanet.com/create-module-magento-2-1471/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magento 2 advocates the use of composer for managing modules, when you install a module through composer it is added to `vendor/<vendor-name>/<module>`.

You should not edit any code inside the vendor folder. If you’re developing your own module or if you want to continue development of an existing module you add your files or clone a git repo to `app/code/<vendor-name>/<module>`.

If you later want to distribute this custom module you initialize a git repo and create a composer package. Now others will be able to download and install your module as a composer package, in their `<vendor>` folder.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the vendor folder is the target of composer installation (and later reinstallation), which is the reason not to do manual work in that branch of the file system. That goes a long way to settling by mind as to why app/code is the place to do manual ad hoc development.

Comment: I have a module i want to use i put on app/code/Company/ModuleName but this module as some dependencies. If i log into this folder and do composer install the "vendor" folder is inside this . but It is not detected. Where should i add the dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Take note that in Magento 2x, You should not touch the vendor folder because the core modules of magento resides in that folder. and if you modify a single code or module in that folder, and you are planning in the future to upgrade your magento to the latest version available. You will experience a major problem because when you upgrade magento 2. Those codes or module that you edited in the vendor folder will give a conflict to the new version. The best thing you can do is extend a vendor module for you to be safe. and if your magento installation has no app/code folder. you can manually add it.

The correct way of creating or extending a module is to create it under app/code/vendorname/modulename you can refer to this link: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Hi guys correct me if I'm wrong. but as far with my experience in magento 2. vendor module should not be touched.

Thank you,
MazeStricks

Comment: app/code/VENDORNAME/MODULENAME is correct sructure, not app/code/VENDRNAME_MODULENAME. Note that it is a subdirectory, and not one directory for all modules of one VENDORNAME.

Answer (score 2):

I (the original poster) later stumbled on this word from the horse's mouth:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Just-Ask-Alan/Why-two-locations-to-develop-themes/m-p/30147

An excerpt:

Here are some key directories to try and clarify their roles:

- app/design is where to locally develop a theme to have it picked up during development.
- vendor is where things go if you get a "released" package from somewhere (Marketplace, or internally) - Composer downloads into this area.
- pub/static is where files are *generated* from the theme. These are the files the web browser downloads. All fallback rules, theme inheritance, etc is all resolved by this stage.

... and there's quite a bit more in that same comment, and subsequent Q&A comments.

Answer (score 1):

All core module located at `vendor/magento` folder

Our developed extension we need to place it to `app/code` folder

You are right there is no vendor directory. Here vendor means your custom module name. As an example your module name `Test_HelloWorld` then you have to create below directory and your `Test_HelloWorld` module code place into it.

```
app/code/Test/HelloWorld
```

Comment: On my magento 2.1 installation there's no code directory in the [magentoroot]/app folder.  There IS however a [magentoroot]/vendor/ folder, in which there are many vendors' specific folders. One of these is:
[magentoroot]/vendor/magento/...  containing all of magento's modules. Also within [magentoroot]/vendor/ are about 25 other vendor subfloders containing their modules.  That's why I say that it looks to me like [magentoroot]/vendor/ is the place to put modules.

Comment: You have to create code directory in `code` directory in `app` folder and place all module in it.